# ¿Cómo puedo ocultar y mostrar un WebView mediante un botón en un Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Necesito que al oprimir un botón un WebView aparezca y desaparezca,  pero no tengo claro como hacer esto en un Fragment.

Este el código del xml

```
<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Marlon" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/wView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp">

    </WebView>

</LinearLayout>
```

y este es el código de la actividad

```
package com.example.facien.apliacionfacien;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class FInformatica1 extends Fragment {

Button btn1;
WebView wView;
TextView textView2;

public FInformatica1() {
    // Required empty public constructor


}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    textView2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    wView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.wView);

    textView2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            wView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });


}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_finformatica1, container, false);

    String url = "file:///android_asset/denominacionInformatica.html";
    WebView view = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.wView);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.loadUrl(url);

    TextView view12 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    String ff = "Descripción";
    view12.setText(ff);


    return  rootView;

}
}
```

Este es el código de la Activity donde están los fragmentos

```
package com.example.facien.apliacionfacien;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;

public class InformaticaActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener{

Button btn1;
WebView wView;

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_informatica);




    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);



        }

// Métodos de la interfaz ActionBar.TabListener
@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

}

// Métodos de la interfaz ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener
@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.

 public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
 /**
 * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
 * fragment.

 private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

 public PlaceholderFragment() {
 }

 /**
 * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
 * number.
 */
/**
 public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
 PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
 Bundle args = new Bundle();
 args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
 fragment.setArguments(args);
 return fragment;
 }

 }
 */

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */



public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {



    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        Fragment tabFragment = null;

        switch (position){
            case 0:
                tabFragment = new FInformatica1();
                break;
            case 1:
                tabFragment = new Finformatica2();
                break;
            case 2:
                tabFragment = new Finforamtica3();
                break;
        }
        return tabFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 2 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        String section = null;

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                section = "SECTION 1";
                break;
            case 1:
                section = "SECTION 2";
                break;
            case 2:
                section = "SECTION 3";
                break;
        }
        return section;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bueno, lo primero que debes tener en cuenta es el ciclo de vida de un Fragment. Según la documentación, en el método `onCreate()` no deberías estar haciendo más que iniciar algunas variables, usar el `savedInstanceState`, o todo aquello que no este relacionado con la UI del Fragment (View's hierarchy). Pues este método se invoca cuando se ha creado el Fragmento, pero su UI aun no está lista (no deberías tener acceso al método `findViewById` desde ahí). Cuando se crea la UI del Fragmento, se invoca el método `onCreateView()` y es aquí donde deberías estar haciendo toda la lógica referente a la UI, como iniciar las vistas y establecer el `onClickListener` para el textView2.

Pasa la lógica que tienes en el `onCreate()`al método `onViewCreated()` y me cuentas si te funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes modificar el ancho y el alto del `WebView` y asignarles como valor `0`. De esa manera el `WebView` desaparecerá.

```
@Override 
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                   Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_finformatica1, container, false);

    textView2=(Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    wView=(WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.wView);

    textView2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
        @Override 
        public void onClick(View v) { 
           // wView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
           android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = wView.getLayoutParams(); 
           layoutParams.width = 0; 
           layoutParams.height = 0;
           wView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        } 
    }); 

    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Mi mayor problema es que no se como llamar a un botón para que solo aparezca en un fragment,  ya que cuando lo pongo sale en los tres fragment y como llamar a su evento click.

Comment: Tienes un `ViewPager`?

Comment: si, en la Activity donde están los fragments, ya actualicé eso en la pregunta

Comment: @MarlonYela    tienes creados cada uno de los fragmentos y en cada uno tienes un `WebView`?

Comment: si, tengo 3 fragmentos y en cada uno un WebView

Comment: Todavía no has encontrado solución a tu problema?

Comment: la verdad todavía no, por eso opté por realizar un archivo html, en el cual mediante css logré hacer lo que tenía pensado con Android Studio.